# How do I mount a linux cd on mac?

Tags: linux, windows-10, mac, mount

I have a cd that contains some software that can be installed either on a mac, linux or windows.

When the cd in inserted into the drive on a mac, it automounts and only the mac binaries are visible but not the windows or linux ones. Similarly, on windows, the cd also automounts and only the windows software can be  seen. However, I need to retrieve the linux binaries. I have access to only a windows and mac physical machines but not linux. I tried using linux virtual machine but that did not work. How do I retrieve the linux binaries off this cd?

Comment: I don't have one to test, but what happens when you look at Disk Utility [set to Show All Devices]?

Comment: It is likely that the Linux side uses a filesystem that the Mac does not support out of the box. If you can determine the filesystem OSXFuse might be able to help...

Comment: It still shows as the mac disk " Mac OS Standard", 305.6MB. But now I know that the device is disk5s0. Can't still see the linux or windows part

Comment: @SteveChambers How do I determine the Filesystem?

Comment: Disk utility **MAYBE.** Best to mount it on a Linux computer

Comment: @K7AAY this is exactly what I am NOT asking

Comment: @wander95 Mount it on a PC booted from a Linux LiveUSB flash drive, and copy the files onto another USB flash drive formatted for FAT32. Once copied, shut down Linux, remove both flash drives, and power back up into MacOS.